# Print PHP message to form through Ajax/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a jquery/bootstrap form. My php is checking against the database if an email address is already in use.

If the email address is in use, the following is called but to a new window.

`echo'<p class="error">An account already exists for this email address. Please use a different email address</p>'`;

This all works fine but now I want the error message to show up on the Jquery form. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this.

I know I have to use this handler, but I don't know where to put the error message or how this code knows which error message to read from the php. Additionally, I would like the error message to show up next to the email field of the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing the error message can be performed in the `success` property. The function can accept a `data` argument (the response from `process.php`).

```
success: function(data){
    //does data contain p.error?
    //get the contents of p.error, display it on the current page

    //for example:
    if( $(data).find("p.error.name").length ){
        //process name error here
        nameError = $(data).find("p.error.name").text();
        console.log(nameError);
    }
    if( $(data).find("p.error.email").length ){
        //process email error here
        emailError = $(data).find("p.error.email").text();
        console.log(emailError);
    }
}
```

The success function defined above assumes `process.php` looks something like this:

```
<div>
<p class="error name">Please enter a name.</p>
<p class="error email">Your email address is invalid.</p>

<!-- some other stuff here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I see, so "success" will print anything that process.php prints, even if it's not a "successful" submission? I think I am getting confused by semantics here. How do I differentiate between messages? Say I want one for email and others for first, last name. How does the function know which one was called in process.php?

Comment: that is correct - the success property of the ajax call is for a successful response from the server; it does not indicate that the form was successfully submitted (in terms of validation, etc).
Perhaps you can modify `process.php` so that `p.error` contains `data-` attributes or additional classes to indicate the error types. in that case, the success callback would look for `p.error.name` or `p.error.email`